# Recursively check for property on prototype and delete it from prototype if it exists

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to write code to delete a property in an object. If it is    inherited, it must go up the chain and delete itfrom the ancestor.
So far I have come up with this (doesnot work):

```
// My objects:
   var pro = {'a':1};
    var pro2 = Object.create(pro);
    var pro3 = Object.create(pro2);
```

//  -----------------------------------------------------

```
    function deleteProp(obj, prop){
        console.log(obj,prop)
        //get own properties
        var ownprop = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);


        for(var i=0 ;i <ownprop.length; i++){
            if (prop === ownprop[i]){
                delete obj.ownprop[i];
            }
            else{ 

           //get the parent
                var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
                console.log(parent);
                while (Object.getPrototypeOf(parent)!== Object.prototype){

             //recursive call
                    deleteProp(parent, prop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will `delete Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)[prop]` not do the trick?

Comment: I think you want `delete obj[ownprop[i]]` instead of `delete obj.ownprop[i]`. Your `else` also seems to be in the wrong position--it will cause the prototype chain to be traversed again and again for each property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need recursion here--a simple while loop will suffice.

```
function deleteProp(obj, prop) {
  while (obj && obj !== Object.prototype) {
    delete obj[prop];
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
}
```

The check for `obj` is necessary because an object may have no prototype, for instance if it was created with `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: This is right. Didnt think of Object.create(null) scenario. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the output, this should do what you want.

```js
var pro = {'a':1};
var pro2 = Object.create(pro);
var pro3 = Object.create(pro2);

function deleteProp(obj, prop) {
  do {
    delete obj[prop];
  }
  while ((obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
}

console.log('before', pro.a, pro2.a, pro3.a);
deleteProp(pro3, 'a');
console.log('after', pro.a, pro2.a, pro3.a);
```

**Edit:** will this do the trick?

Comment: Won't this only go up one level? Also, you don't need to check `if (proto[prop])`; delete doesn't care if the property actually exists or not.

Comment: Not sure, the OP did not specify how he "derives" beyond his example.

Comment: @torazaburo: This will go up only one level but the core lesson is correct: use `Object.getPropertyOf()`. We can assume that people are smart enough to roll up their own solutions if they need to do it recursively (otherwise they should either comment or ask a new question)

Comment: This code works in only this scenario. If I have a property pro3.b =3 ; and I want to delete that, it will not work. I am trying to create a recursive function that will check for a property in the object, check if it is an own property and delete it. Else it will go upn the prototypal chain and delete it from the parent. It should go up till the very end.

Comment: `If I have a property pro3.b =3`, if you assign it like that then no, because you are not assigning it to the prototype. EDIT: missed the part about ownprop.

Comment: @javascriptnovice see my edit, won't that do what you want?

Comment: I dont think it would work if I pass object as pro3 and property as 'a':  console.log('before', pro.a, pro2.a, pro3.a);
    deleteProp(pro3, 'a');
    console.log('after', pro.a, pro2.a, pro3.a); Answer: before (1,1,1) after(1,1,1)

Comment: Ah, saw that someone beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts!! I guess the code works now.